# Why SetInterval doesn't work (it works only once)

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I made a progress bar for `.swf`.

**Code in `<head>`:**

```
function ProgressBar(){

setTimeout(function (){

if (swfobject.getObjectById("Object").IsPlaying()) {

var TotalFrames = swfobject.getObjectById("Object").TotalFrames();
console.log(console.log("TotalFrames: " + TotalFrames));

var TCurrentFrame = swfobject.getObjectById("Object").CurrentFrame;
console.log(TCurrentFrame);
}

}, 200);


}
```

**Code in `<body>`:**

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="600" height="600" id="Object">
        <param name="movie" value="./Flash.swf">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="loop" value="false">
        <param name="play" value="false"> 
        <param name="quality" value="high">

        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="./Flash.swf" width="600" height="600" id="Object">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="loop" value="false">
        <param name="play" value="false"> 
        <param name="quality" value="high">

        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->

      </object>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
ProgressBar();
})
```

I want the output `TotalFrame` and `CurrentFrame`, but the function `SetInterval` shows the result only once.

**Output in console log:**

```
TotalFrames: 745
undefined
102
```

How do I write this? What is the error?

Comment: Regarding your edited question: are you saying it still doesn't work even after you changed to `setInterval()` instead of the `setTimeout()` that you originally had?

Comment: @nnnnnn no-no, all work now, thanks

Comment: OK, good, but please don't edit your questions to replace broken code with code from the answer(s) because then when people read your question later it doesn't make sense. I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps because you aren't using `setInterval` like in your question's title but `setTimeout` in your code ;)

Comment: @NikTip No problem ;) Make sure that you get the difference between both. Also please note that you can actually use `setTimeout`, but you would have to start a new timer within each `setTimeout` callback to create the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProgressBar` function is using `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`. `setTimeout()` only fires the timeout once.